# Javascript FileReader with multiple files , how iterate files name?

Tags: javascript, php, image

I'm trying to write a multi upload image logic. This is the code i use:

```
function readURL(input,index) {

                    for (var z = 0; z < input.files.length; z++) {

                        var FileZ=input.files[z];


                        if (input.files && input.files[z]) {
                            var reader = new FileReader();  
                            reader.onload = function (e) {
                                var i = new Image();
                                i.src=e.target.result;
                                i.onload = function(){
                                    //ajax crop to 500x350
                                    var arrExt = FileZ.name.split('.');
                                    if(i.width>=500 && i.height>=350) {
                                        $.ajax({
                                            url: 'ajax/cropImage.php',
                                            type: 'POST',
                                            data: 'base64='+e.target.result+"&ext="+arrExt[(arrExt.length-1)],
                                            success: function(data) {

                                                //here i insert the image in html.
                                            }
                                        });

                                    } else {
                                        alert("Image too big");
                                    }
                                };
                            }                   
                            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[z]);
                        }
                    }

                }
```

This code works correctly, i can upload and see after ajaxCrop.php the resulting images. The problem comes when i try to upload image with different extensions. If i try to upload one jpg and one png, only one of this photo will be cropped. The problem is in

```
var arrExt = FileZ.name.split('.');
```

Here the file name is always the same, at z=0 name='image.jpg' and at z=1 name='image.jpg' (the name should be 'image.png'). So i get an error when i try to crop a 'false' jpg... How i can get the correct 'name at index'?

Comment: this might be happening because your ajax call is asynchronous. It will not wait for your for loop's execution. So by the time the ajax call is made, the for loop is in a different cycle. Try adding `async: False` to your ajax call or consider restructuring your code.